# How to get time in no space format ? javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to save data to database in order of their upload, I decided to use current time in ISO, like if date is -> 29 June 2021 Tuesday, 19(hour):36(minute):45(seconds), I extracted time from it as 193645 this ensured to display data according to time for that day,

but if the seconds is single digit for example(14(hour):32(minute):05(seconds)) but then it displays 14325 without 0.

And if possible I want the time for this date - (29 June 2021 Tuesday, 19(hour):36(minute):45(seconds))

to (without those brackets) - 21(for year)06(for month)29(for day)19(for hour)36(for minute)45(for seconds)

```js
let _today = new Date().toISOString()
let dateToday = new Date(_today)
_time = dateToday.getHours().toString() + dateToday.getMinutes().toString() + dateToday.getSeconds().toString()
console.log(_time)
```

This is my current code

Comment: You can use [padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) to prefix strings that are to short

Comment: thanks :) worked well, now if possible provide a way to ad year,month,day in start

Comment: Well the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) should provide you will all the information you need. [Year](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear), [Month](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) and [Day](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the separator symbols and take the substring you need.

Like in this function

```
symbolless = (date) => date.toISOString().replace(/[\-\.\:ZT]/g,"").substr(2,10)
```

Handling timezones is a little more difficult as JavaScript uses UTC-0 as the timezone for `.toISOString()`.

Get the timezone in negative minutes using `.getTimezoneOffset()` and multiply with -60000 to get the correct offset in milliseconds. **Be aware** the timezone will depend on the machines local timezone, so deployments or users in other timezones will yield different results when running the command (this might be fixed in the future with the introduction of [temporal](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/index.html)).

```js
symbolless = (date) => new Date(date.getTime() + date.getTimezoneOffset() * -60000)
                               .toISOString()
                               .replace(/[\-\.\:ZT]/g,"")
                               .substr(2,10)
```

Running the new function `symbolless(new Date('August 19, 1975 23:15:30 UTC'))` will yield `7508200015` in my timezone. In the following format:

```
YYMMDDHHMM
7508200015
```

This is correct as the date is now in UTC+1.

Comment: Perfect! although the time returned is not same for my local time zone it is in UTC, can you explain the reason ?

Comment: date.toString().replace(/[\-\.\ \:ZT]/g,"").substr(5,12) this worked in my case, tho in this also month is coming before year, if you could help that would be really helpful

Comment: I will take another look at it

Comment: Use `.toISOString()` instead of `.toString()`.